# Jetpack Compose: How to measure time taken to render the UI?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I'm trying Jetpack compose for one of the features in my app. For page load tracking purpose, I want to track the time taken to render the Fragment UI. How can I do that in case of Jetpack compose?

Answer (score 0):

```
var time = remember { currentTimeInMillis() }

Composables(...) {
innerMostComposable{
//If this loads, you can record the time
time -= currentTimeMillis() // this is it
}
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to generically find out when the UI rendering comples in compose?

Comment: Could you elaborate "generically"?

Comment: My compose UI is generated based on a JSON obtained from server (kind of Server driver UI). The resulting composable view is then rendered in a container fragment. So I cant add measureTimeInMillis for the last item in the composable view.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68727008/how-can-i-measure-the-render-time-in-jetpack-compose