# How can I measure the render time in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I am evaluating whether to use drawable icons or font icons and therefore want to measure each implementations rendering time.

I have already tried usings Kotlin's `measureTimeMillis(())` without any luck.
Calculating the time through `System.currentTimeInMillis()` seems to not work either.

Is there any professional approach to measuring the render time of a Composable reliably?

Comment: Have you tried `Firebase Performance SDK`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's A new tool in the android development kit. It is called as Macro Benchmarking. Allows you to put trace points and measure time as well. Check that out on the official youtube channel or the docs. Other than that as pointed out in the comment above, I guess Firebase may also offer something similar. But if you want precise data at development time, go for the Macro thing