# How to measure Jetpack Compose complete drawing time?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

When I want to measure the drawing time for custom view, I can use the below function.

```
override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas)
    val elapsedTime= measureTimeMillis {
        myDeepHierarchyCustomeDrawing.draw(canvas)
    }
    Log.d("Tracking", "Time used $elapsedTime")
}
```

However, for Jetpack Compose, when I draw the view, the below elapse time is no longer accurate.
The function seems to get spawn off as a different thread, hence the elapsed time to finish before the drawing finish.

```
@Composable
override fun Content() {
    val elapsedTime= measureTimeMillis {
        MyDeepHierarchyJetpackComposeDrawing()
    }
    Log.d("Tracking", "Time used $elapsedTime")
}
```

Hence my question is, how can I measure the time used by Jetpack Compose to complete a complex deep hierarchical jetpack compose function drawing?

Answer (score -1):

This question has been asked many times before Eel-Eye.
Anyway, per the [docs](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/mental-model#parallel), the entire behaviour can be explained. Specifically, the lines

> This optimization means a composable function might execute within a
> pool of background threads. If a composable function calls a function
> on a ViewModel, Compose might call that function from several threads
> at the same time.

Now, you see, as far as the current state of Compose can be considered, there IS no specific method, or for that matter, even a reliable workaround, in order to calculate the render time. There is, however, a very nice tool in Studio for Profiling, which is meant for this exact same purpose.

It is known as Macro Benchmarking. You can read [the docs](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/macrobenchmark-intro#:%7E:text=The%20Jetpack%20Macrobenchmark%20library%20allows,JSON%20file%20with%20more%20detail.), and then refer to [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0adLO2VRJtc&vl=en) for a clearer understanding.

You can also see a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68576360/15880865) and check the comments below my answer which call the question a duplicate and then point you to another (older) question which actually has accepted my answer regarding the two approaches I told them, one of them being Macro-Benchmarking.